# Render UI element in front of others programmatically without sibling index (2D)

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, 2d

I have a grid of buttons (3 by 3 for this example). When a button is clicked, it rotates 180 degrees. As it rotates towards 90 degrees, it increases in scale. Once it passes 90 degrees and rotates towards 180, it decreases back to it's original size.

Unfortunately, this is a 2D game so it seems that the layers are determined by the hierarchy, which is created in the order the buttons are spawned. This causes some ugly overlap issues when the tiles scale up, when I really just want whatever button is clicked to be brought to the front.

The common solution seems to be to set the sibling index, but that will not work in this case because the buttons are held in a canvas using a Grid Layout Group, and changing the sibling index causes the buttons to be reordered.

Answer (score 0):

Add a canvas component to your button and use sortOrder to modify the rendering order of it.

Comment: That seems to have worked, except the button on click no longer works. Seems a bit odd to me, I don't see why having a canvas would prevent clicking

Comment: Modify the canvas rect transform to avoid it.